# Java Integer Wrapper behavior

Tags: java, wrapper

What is the explanation for this behavior?

```
class test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

    Integer i = 4000, j = 4000;
    System.out.println(i==j);
    Integer k = 50, n =50;
    System.out.println(k==n);

    }

}
```

Output:
False
True

Comment: From javadoc `Cache to support the object identity semantics of autoboxing for values between -128 and 127 (inclusive) as required by JLS.`

Comment: If you are comparing object references, you should get false everywhere.  The reason you are getting true in the second case is because both `Integer` instances are pointing to the same object in the integer pool.